# Remove part of 'one word' string Python

Tags: python, regex, string, python-3.x, nlp

I have this list with part of speech tags and their specifics: `['VNW(pers,pron,nomin,red,2v,ev)', 'WW(pv,tgw,met-t)', 'LID(bep,stan,rest)']`. As you can see there are no spaces between the characters, so it can be seen as one word.

Now I need a new list with only the part of speech tags, like this `['VNW', 'WW', 'LID']`. 
I tried removing the brackets and everything in them with a regex like this `pattern = re.compile(r'(.*)')`.
I also tried to match only the capital letters, but I can't get it right. Suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regular expression is not need for this case. Split by `(`; then get the first part only.

```
>>> 'VNW(pers,pron,nomin,red,2v,ev)'.split('(')
['VNW', 'pers,pron,nomin,red,2v,ev)']
>>> 'VNW(pers,pron,nomin,red,2v,ev)'.split('(')[0]
'VNW'
```

---

```
>>> xs = ['VNW(pers,pron,nomin,red,2v,ev)', 'WW(pv,tgw,met-t)',
          'LID(bep,stan,rest)']
>>> [x.split('(')[0] for x in xs]
['VNW', 'WW', 'LID']
```

Answer (score 1):

Some of the possible solutions are:

**Removing Brackets using loop**

```
l = ['VNW(pers,pron,nomin,red,2v,ev)', 'WW(pv,tgw,met-t)', 'LID(bep,stan,rest)']
for i in range(len(l)):
    i1,i2=l[i].find('('),l[i].find(')')
    l[i]=l[i][:i1]+l[i][i2+1:]
print l
```

**Using Regex**

```
import re
pattern = r'\([^)]*\)'
l = ['VNW(pers,pron,nomin,red,2v,ev)', 'WW(pv,tgw,met-t)', 'LID(bep,stan,rest)']
for i in range(len(l)):
    l[i] = re.sub(pattern, '', l[i])
print l
```

**Output:** ['VNW', 'WW', 'LID']

Answer (score 0):

Short solution using `str.find()` function:

```
l = ['VNW(pers,pron,nomin,red,2v,ev)', 'WW(pv,tgw,met-t)', 'LID(bep,stan,rest)']
result = [i[:i.find('(')] for i in l]
```

---

`result` contents:

```
['VNW', 'WW', 'LID']
```

Answer (score 0):

For example:

```
In [102]: s=['VNW(pers,pron,nomin,red,2v,ev)', 'WW(pv,tgw,met-t)', 'LID(bep,stan,rest)']
In [103]: [x.split('(', 1)[0] for x in s]
Out[103]: ['VNW', 'WW', 'LID']
```